# use xerces c with Clion IDE on Windows

Tags: windows, mingw, clion, xerces-c

I'm actually looking for a way to create apps with xerces c++ with Clion from JetBrains.

I've installed xerces-c++ with Cmake and MinGW, so I have all the stuff in C:\Program Files (x86)\xerces-c

this is my projet with Clion

[CMakeLists.txt :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rG5O.png)

[and the configurator.cpp:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MeDc.png)

and the response to build is :"fatal error: xercesc/dom/DOM.hpp: No such file or directory"

Comment: Instead of showing the source code in an PNG image located elsewhere, it would be better if you would just place the source code directly in the question. You can get nice syntax highlighting with https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting   . For C++ you could use `<!-- language: lang-cxx -->` and for a CMake script you could use `<!-- language: lang-none -->` .

Answer (score 0):

That's ok, I solved my problem. I correct the cmake file like this

1- [New CmakeLists.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pb2qT.png)

2- need to import FindXercesC.cmake to th project root